# What is the impact on US total debt interest expense if interest rates were to rise by X bps?

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request

What is the impact on US total debt (eg. the "Total US Debt" figure [here](https://www.usdebtclock.org/)) interest expense -- ie. the combined expense for both the Federal gov as well as individuals -- going forward w/in the next 1-3 years if interest rates were to rise by X bps?

Where can I see a breakdown of total US debt by maturity to understand this better? Is there a way to understand what % of total US debt is recurring? (My idea on this being that there is some % of total US debt that is 1. recurring, 2. generally considered to be non-discretionary, and 3. of relatively short maturity, so any rate raises would result in all of that continual debt raising total US interest expense quickly)